# How a pointer to an array works in this context?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I was asked by an interviewer what the following C program will output

```c
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *prt = (int*) (&a+1);
    
    printf("%d %d", *(a+1), *(prt-1));
```

which prints

```
2 5
```

My answer was wrong for the second number. I realize that I don't really understand what's going on with a pointer to an array (which is already a pointer to the first element of the array). What is `*ptr` really doing here?

Comment: `&a` is not a pointer to an `int` but to an array `int[5]`. If you add `+1` to such a pointer you will advance past the array instead of past first element. Therefore the `-1` was required to avoid accessing illegal memory after the array.

Comment: `int *prt = (int*) (&a+1);` would be better written as `int *prt = *(&a+1);`.

Comment: @mch: `*(&a+1)` is not defined by the C standard. The standard gives meaning to pointers “one beyond” an object only for purposes of pointer arithmetic (C 2018 6.5.6). Per C 2018 6.5.3.2, the operand of `*` must point to an actual object or a function, not merely have a type of “pointer to object” or “pointer to function”. Both `(int*) (&a+1)` and `*(&a+1)` are not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the expression

```
&a
```

is `int ( * )[5]` and the expression

```
&a + 1
```

points to the memory past the last element of the array.

Then this pointer is interpreted as a pointer of the type `int *`.

```
(int*) (&a+1)
```

So this expression

```
(prt-1)
```

points to the last element of the array and the last element is outputted using the expression

```
*(prt-1)
```

This expression

```
(a+1)
```

points to the second element of the array and this element is outputted using the expression

```
*(a+1)
```

Comment: While `&a+1` points “one beyond” the array `a`, this is only applicable for pointer arithmetic, not for conversions. The C standard does not define the behavior of `(int*) (&a+1)` except that converting it back to `int (*)[5]` yields something equal to `&a+1` (C 2018 6.3.2.3 7). It does not guarantee that `(int *)(&a + 1)` yields the same as `a+5`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sizeof( a ) is equal to 5 * sizeof( int ). You comment in essence means that these values are not equal to each other.

Comment: No, it does not. The C standard does not define pointer types to behave solely as numerical addresses. It does not specify they obey laws of arithmetic as if they were solely numerical addresses. It defines arithmetic and other operations on pointers only within certain bounds, and `(int *) (&a+1)` transgresses those bounds.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, it means exactly what I pointed out.  The address of the expression ( void * )a + sizeof( a ) is the same as ( void * )a + 5 * sizeof( int ).   Otherwise the subscript operator will not work and you are saying that indeed the subscript operator does not work.

Comment: `(void *) a + sizeof (a)` is not defined by the C standard; C 6.5.6 2 requires a pointer operand to `+` to be a pointer to a complete object type, and `void` is not complete. If we consider instead `(char *) a + sizeof a` and `(char *)a + 5 * sizeof *a`, then those do yield equivalent pointers, because the standard explicitly says we can treat an object (`a`) as an array of bytes, and both of these add to the number of bytes in the array to its start, which is defined by 6.5.6 8. But both of these expressions yield a `char *`, so we have two `char *` which point to the same place.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I made a mistake in hurry. I meant ( char * )a.

Comment: In contrast, `a+5` and `&a+1` are not the same type; they are `int *` and `int (*)[5]`. Although they point to “the same place” in some conceptual way, this is not defined by the C standard, and conversion between them is not fully defined by the C standard. There is no rule in C that pointers must behave as if arithmetic were performed on numerical addresses. They may be represented with compound data structures, not a flat address space, and conversions between them may act in unexpected ways.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The array a is aligned by the value sizeof( int ). So &a + 1 is also aligned by this value because each element of the array also is such aligned.

Comment: It is similar to `INT_MAX + 3 - INT_MAX`. The C standard does not guarantee this evaluates to 3. Although it would if expressions used ordinary integer arithmetic, the C standard only defines the behavior of expressions up to certain bounds. Outside those bounds, the behavior is not defined. Overflow may occur, and machine characteristics or compiler optimization may produce effects other than producing 3. Similarly, in `(int *) (&a+1)`, we exceed the bounds for which the standard defines pointer operations, and compiler optimization may produce unexpected effects.

Comment: Alignment is irrelevant; the cause for the failure here is a lack of specification of the behavior by the C standard about operations on a pointer pointing beyond the end of an object, not anything to do with alignment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Neither compiler will produce an unexpected result due to the pointer arithmetic as as I already said due to the expression sizeof( a ) == 5 * sizeof( int )(.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What you are trying to proof is that 2 + 2 is equal to 5.

Comment: Given that `&a + 1` points one beyond the array `a`, show us the rule in the C standard that says converting it to `int *`, with `(int *) (&a + 1)`, produces a pointer that compares equal to `a + 5`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is it a next attempt to proof that sizeof( a ) is not equal to 5 * sizeof( int )?:)

Comment: @EricPostpischil At first try to proof the following simple relation. Let you have an array of two elements int a[2];. Now try to proof that ( char * )a + sizeof( int ) is not equal to the value of a + 1. When you will proof this let me know.:)

Comment: The C standard does not define `(char *) a + sizeof *a == a+1` because it does not satisfy the constraints in C 2018 6.5.9 2, particularly “both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types”. If, however, we evaluate `(char *) a + sizeof *a == (char *) (a+1)`, then we know the former is the first byte of `a[1]` by 6.3.2.3 7 (we can convert a pointer to an object to a pointer to a character type and access it as an array of the bytes representing it) and 6.2.5 20 (an array type describes a contiguously allocated set of objects),…

Comment: … and we know the latter is also the first byte of `a[1]` by 6.5.6 (addition to a pointer) and 6.3.2.3 7. So this evaluation will produce true (1), by 6.5.9 6.

Comment: So, you try this “gotcha” as if it shows something. But it just shows you are ignoring the rules of the C standard. Computers are machines. They do not automatically produce results according to the rules of mathematics. Nothing prevents us from programming a compiler such that `2 + 2` produces 5. The C standard does not require pointer operations to obey rules that you prefer. It says what it says, and it does not fully define the result of `(int *) (&a+1)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I have understood you was unable to proof that ( char * )a + sizeof( int ) is equal to the value of a + 1. So now you presented a new argument that for computers 2 + 2 is equal to 5. By the way you must to write a C Standard defect about the pointer arithmetic that sizeof( a ) is not equal to 5 * sizeof( int ).:) That is that when you  are using the loop char *p = ( char * )a; for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( int ); ++p ); the value of the pointer p is not equal to the value of the expression a + 1! You are expecting the value 4  but your computer yields the value 5!:)